# I am unable to style a checkbox ! On clicking on it , the colour should change, however i am unable to position it

Tags: html, css, reactjs

The white part should be on the tick. At first whole thing should be black and it should turn white on click.I am trying it on Storybook. Also, please help me with poisitioning.
[image]

```
  <span className={css.cb}>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxInput" name=""/>
      <label for="checkboxInput"></label>
  </span>
```

Here is the CSS !

```
 @import "base.scss";

    .cb {
     display: inline-block;

     position: absolute;
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     left: 10px;
     top: 5px;

     background: #000000;
     border-radius: 5px;
     box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
   }

    .cb label {

    display: inline-block;

    position: absolute;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    left: 4px;
    top: 10px;

    background: #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
   }

   .cb input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
      background: #FFFFFF;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See if i understand your problem
.You want to change the class of span on the bases of click on checkbox.For that you need state of react class , method to handle click on checkbox , and little change in your present code

setting state

```
constructor(props){
super(props)
this.state = {
 isChecked = false
}
 this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
}
```

this may be your constructor of class

below we are setting method

```
handleClick(e){
e.preventDefault()
this.setState({"isChecked":!this.state.isChecked})
}
```

this can be your method

this contain some changes needed in your present code.

```
<span className={this.state.isChecked?"yourClassForWhiteBackground":"yourClassForBlackBackground"}>
    <input type="checkbox" onClick={this.handleClick}value="1" id="checkboxInput" name=""/>
  <label for="checkboxInput"></label>
</span>
```

hope is the solution you are looking for